# Scaffold-DbContext creating model for table without a primary key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create DBcontext and corresponding model for a particular table in ASP.NET core MVC application. This table doesn't have any primary key.

I am running following Scaffold-DbContext command-

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXXXX;User Id=XXXXXXX;password=XXXXXXX" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -t TABLE_NAME -force -verbose
```

In Package Manager Console, I can see this verbose output-

```
...............
...............
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.TABLE_NAME'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.TABLE_NAME'.
```

My Environment is - VS2015 update3, .NET core 1.0.0, ASP.NET MVC core application.

Is there anyway to create a model for a table without primary key?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Support for complex types (those that don't have an entity key) in EF Core is on the backlog: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/246. That's why any attempt to reverse engineer a table without a primary key defined won't work at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Any workaround available at this moment? I am only looking to read data from table; No Insert/Update/Delete operations required on this table.

Comment: 1.5 yrs passed by. Is it still the same case? Can we still not scaffold tables without primary key?

Comment: The latest version of the reverse engineer tooling still requires a PK to be defined on a table for model generation.

Comment: It's March 2018.. Sad.

Comment: 2 years and still a problem. microsoft wtf.

Comment: Answering @SunnyTambi... you can skip the tables you want on the scaffolding process this is the line i am using... Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-XXXX;Database=ENDOC_BASSETTE;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Tables "[dbo].[Customer]","[dbo].[customer_roles]","[dbo].[newusers]","[dbo].[company]" -OutputDir Models -Force -DataAnnotations

Comment: That is now possible with EF Core 3.0 which is currently in preview

Comment: @KevinDimey How ? Can't find documentation anywhere.

Comment: @diegorodny According to the latest docs, in order for `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate an entity type, the database table must have a primary key. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

Comment: Thanks for info Mike. I ended up using ef core power tools for vs studio and it generated entities just fine.