# How call tables without primary key with entity framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I am doing an asp.net core api with odata. My tables in database has no primary key and I do not have permission to change the database. I use below command to call my database:

> "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source = 192.168.11.1\sql2016;Initial Catalog=SeeMiddle;persist security info=True;user id=Iaas;password=Iaas123!@#" Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.SqlServer -d -c SeeMiddleContext -o Models\Entities --force"

and I encounter below errors for every tables:

> Unable to identify the primary key for table 'cmn.ReshteNerkhItem'.
>
> Unable to generate entity type for table 'cmn.ReshteNerkhItem'.

how can I work with a database that has any primary key in asp.net core??

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349080/ef-core-how-add-primary-key

Comment: Sorry, This address doesn't work in my case!

Comment: you have decorate class property as [Key]

Comment: It doesn't bring anything from database

Comment: What version of Ef.Core are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scaffold-DbContext creating model for table without a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701068/scaffold-dbcontext-creating-model-for-table-without-a-primary-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you don't. Entity Framework requires a key. Good news is you can effectively spoof a key if your table doesn't have one. If your table has an implicit key that is distinct then just decorate that property with `[Key]` and you'll be good. The *key* thing is that it has to be a distinct unique value. If you do not have a singular column that does that then you'll need to start using columns together to make a composite key (`[Key, Column(Order = 0)]`.